# Can´t push values on a click event

Tags: reactjs

I´ve designed a clickHandler to set the state of my main component. But it doesn´t seem to be capturing the values very well (console logging results returns nothing) and displaying them on the display component. Don´t really know where´s the problem here:

Calculator class

```
class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value:[]}
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
  handleClick(evt){
 const result= evt.target.value;
this.setState({value : [result] })
console.log(result)
 }



render() {
    return(
            <div id="container">
                <Display id="display" value={this.state.value} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="zero" value={'0'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="one" value={'1'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="two" value={'2'}/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="three" value={'3'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="four" value={'4'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="five" value={'5'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="six" value={'6'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="seven" value={'7'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="eight" value={'8'}  />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="nine" value={'9'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="decimal" value={'.'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="equals" value={'='} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="clear" value={'clear'}  />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="add" value={'+'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="subtract" value={'-'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="multiply" value={'*'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="divide" value={'/'} />
            </div>
)

}
}
```

Button class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
         <input type="button" value={props.value}/>

)
};




export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the onClick handler correcly on your Button Component.
You might wanna set the id as well.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <input type="button" onClick={props.onClick} id={props.id} value={props.value} />

  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Me again :)
You are passing a prop called onClick, but this doesn't mean that it will be called when the button is clicked...

Lets call this prop, in the parent component, 'callback' instead of onClick. This will help remove the confusion.

Now, in the child component assign onClick in the button to this callback property.

```
<input type="button" onClick={(evt) => props.callback(evt)} value={props.value}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it´s working! Could you explain your code? I´m having troubles following what just happened lol

Comment: Lol indeed. But this time I will leave it to you... This is the only way to learn :)